# Cannot POST /api node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am unable to POST a response from an AngularJs form to my Mongo DB database. Here is the code snippet for

**Controller** :

```
   angular.module('myapp')
      .controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $alert, Event) {
        $scope.addEvent = function() {
          Event.save({ eventName: $scope.eventName }).$promise
            .then(function() {
              $scope.eventName = '';
              $scope.addForm.$setPristine();
              $alert({
                content: 'Event has been added.'
              });
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
              $scope.eventName = '';
              $scope.addForm.$setPristine();
              $alert({
                content: response.data.message
              });
            });
        };
      });
```

**Template of form (html)** :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Add Events</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form" method="post" ng-submit="addEvent()" name="addForm">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.eventName.$invalid && addForm.eventName.$dirty }">
          <label class="control-label">Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="eventName" ng-model="eventName" placeholder="Select Event Name Here" required autofocus>
          <div class="help-block text-danger" ng-if="addForm.eventName.$dirty" ng-messages="addForm.eventName.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Event name is required.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="addForm.$invalid">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.post() method** :

```
app.post('/api/events', function (req, res, next) {
   var event = new Event();    // create a new instance of the Event model
    event.name = req.body.eventName;  // set the event name (comes from the request)

    event.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json({ message: 'Event Added!' });
    });

});
```

**Event Schema** :

```
var eventSchema   = new Schema({
  name: String
});
var Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

I can't seem to figure out why am I getting POST /api/events 404 error ?

EDIT : Added GET /api/event routes too

```
app.get('/api/events', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.find(function(err, events) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(events);
    });

});

app.get('/api/events/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.findById(req.params.id, function(err, event) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send(event);
  });
});
```

**Browser Log :**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: EventProvider <- Event
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$injector/unpr?p0=EventProvider%20%3C-%20Event
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:3894:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:4027:39)
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:3899:45
    at getService (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:4027:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:4059:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:4079:23)
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:7460:28
    at link (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular-route.js:913:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/vendor/angular.js:6841:13) <div ng-view="" class="{{pageClass}} ng-scope">
```

Comment: post your Event  service

Comment: Could you share any browser logs you have of the error? Is `res.send(err);` this what is sending the erorr?

Comment: In addition to the `Event` service, it would be nice to see any other relevant express routing. Something throwing a 404 before the request makes it to your `/api/events` handler.

Comment: It's just sending POST /api/events 404 389ms

Comment: I've added them in the question @MattG

Comment: Mind updating your original question with that information. Do you have any middleware in place that might throw a 404?

Comment: Since it is sufficient to provide the event name to test if the server-side code is working properly, I'd try to remove from the equation the client-side code by POSTing the request using cURL or HTTPie.

Comment: I've tried using POSTMAN in chrome , and it works. @burton0

Comment: Ok, so it is reasonable to assume that the problem resides somewhere in the client-side code, right?

Comment: Yes looks like it . @burton0

Comment: Event service? @thetechfreak

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no working knowledge of AngularJS, but I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: I don't know what you exactly mean by Event service. I just have a controller , view on client side.

Also browser logs are updated in the question

Comment: You're passing `Event` into your controller, however it does not exist. Have you defined it somewhere? If so, please attach relevant code.

Comment: I've defined Event on server.js file (where the schema and Mongoose model is there) , code is already in the question

Comment: It sounds like you've defined the Event Model on the backend, and are requiring it on the front-end. Without any additional framework, that isn't possible. The error you're getting in your browser console is because there is no `Event` available to angular. You would need to remove the `Event` dependency from your `angular controller` and replace it with the `$http` dependency.

Comment: Okay ,i created a factory service and it works. Thanks a tonne! @MattG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're trying to share your mongoose model with your angular front-end controller. They are independent of each other.

I modified your `angular controller` to send a `POST` request to the `/api/events` endpoint using the `$http provider`.

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $alert, $http) {
        $scope.addEvent = function() {
            $http.post('/api/events', {
                eventName: $scope.eventName
            }).success(function(response) {
                $scope.eventName = '';
                $scope.addForm.$setPristine();
                $alert({
                    content: 'Event has been added.'
                });
            }).error(function(response) {
                $scope.eventName = '';
                $scope.addForm.$setPristine();
                $alert({
                    content: response.data.message
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question :

I created a factory service

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .factory('Event', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/events/:_id');
  });
```

It's working fine now.